# How to design my pagination form in Laravel 5.6 and get control of it? In another words, how to use Paginator Instance Method?s

Tags: laravel, pagination

How to use Paginator Instance Methods, so I can design my pagination in Laravel 5.6 instead of default?

I tried to use this code dwon but I didn't understand the variable $elements and where did it came from:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
        @endif

        {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
        @foreach ($elements as $element)
            {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
            @if (is_string($element))
                <li class="disabled"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
            @endif

            {{-- Array Of Links --}}
            @if (is_array($element))
                @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                    @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                        <li class="active"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                    @else
                        <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach

        {{-- Next Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
        @else
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: The code you posted is the `default.blade.php` from the laravel source code. What is the question, what you're trying to do and what is the error?

Comment: The error says "Undefined variable: elements". How can I define this variable $elements?

Comment: They are already defined in the `Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator` class and passed to the view as per the docs, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results What are you trying to do? you should add some details if you want an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm trying to get control of the pagination's chape, for exemple: get each side 3 elements and change the arrows in each side to string (next and previous) and so on. Do you know how can I customize that through pagination methods in Laravel 5.6 or through any way?

Comment: You should try to improve your question with the code you use if you want to have a good answer. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. And read Why is [“Can someone help me?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) not an actual question?